# How to supress original line at gawk

Tags: awk

why does gawk write the input line first?

```
     ws@i7$ echo "8989889898 jAAA_ALL_filenames.txt" | gawk  'match($0, /([X0-9\\\-]{9,13})/, arr); {print arr[1];}'
```

my output

```
          8989889898 jAAA_ALL_filenames.txt

          8989889898
```

I do not want that the same first line is printed.

Thanks

Walter

Comment: You got answers to your question but - what are you trying to do with the 3 backslashes in `[X0-9\\\-]`? It's wrong, but idk what to tell you to use instead without knowing what it is you thought it'd do.

Comment: @EdMorton one \ and one - should be in the list of the accepted chars. as - to make it work I have to use \\  and \- in [ ]

Comment: No you don't, there's nothing special about `-` at the start or end of a bracket expression so it doesn't have to be escaped. Just `[X0-9\\-]` is all you need. You also don't need parens around the whole thing so it can just be `/[X0-9\\-]{9,13}/` and then use `print arr[0]` to access the saved string.

Comment: @EdMorton oh ok, thanks for helping me to improve. Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray semicolon in there.

```
$ echo "8989889898 jAAA_ALL_filenames.txt" | gawk  'match($0, /([X0-9\\\-]{9,13})/, arr); {print arr[1];}'
8989889898 jAAA_ALL_filenames.txt
8989889898
$ echo "8989889898 jAAA_ALL_filenames.txt" | gawk  'match($0, /([X0-9\\\-]{9,13})/, arr) {print arr[1];}'
8989889898
```

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon after `match($0, /([X0-9\\\-]{9,13})/, arr)` means that your script is effectively:

```
match($0, /([X0-9\\\-]{9,13})/, arr) { print $0 } # default action block inserted 
1 {print arr[1];} # default condition inserted
```

`match` returns a "true" value so the whole line gets printed.

To fix it, remove the semicolon:

```
match($0, /([X0-9\\\-]{9,13})/, arr) {print arr[1];}
```

Now the code only has one `condition { action }` structure, as you intended, so it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great explanations

Comment: No problem, but I'm wondering why you said thanks to me and then accepted the other answer!

Comment: yes I only can accept one answer and both says the same. But your has more explanations. So sorry that I acceped the other but I also thank you.